# how to reduce horizontal space between figures in tabular

Tags: tables, spacing, floats, horizontal

I'm using this code

```
\begin{figure}[ht]

  \begin{tabular}{ll}

    % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
    \includegraphics[trim = {3.32cm 10.61cm 3.32cm 10.61cm},clip,width=1.75in]{newresults/th1dis} &\includegraphics[trim = {3.32cm 10.61cm 3.32cm 10.61cm},clip,width=1.75in]{newresults/T1dis}\\
    \includegraphics[trim = {3.32cm 10.61cm 3.32cm 10.61cm},clip,width=1.75in]{newresults/th2dis} &\includegraphics[trim = {3.32cm 10.61cm 3.32cm 10.61cm},clip,width=1.75in]{newresults/T2dis}\\
  \end{tabular}
  \medskip
  \caption{my caption.}
\label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}
```

now I want to reduce the horizontal space between the figures which are side by side, is it possible ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you add a screenshot of your result to your question please?

Comment: your title asks about tabularx but the example uses tabular.  you have 2\tabcolsep spacing which you can avoid by using `\begin{tabular}{l@{}l}`  or simply remove the tabular and have two `\includegraphics`.

Comment: thank you David Carlisle. It works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing special about images, here `\includegraphics` is positioned like a letter such as `x`.  A `tabular` soecification of `ll` has `\tabcolsep` spacing around each column so you could use `l@{}l` to remove the middle space or locally in the figure use `\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}` or whatever length you want.